# Redirecting standard input\output in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, stdin

What is the required syntax to redirect standard input/output on Windows PowerShell?

On Unix, we use:

```
$./program <input.txt >output.txt
```

How do I execute the same task in PowerShell?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098366/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-under-windows

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can't hook a file directly to stdin, but you can still access stdin.

```
Get-Content input.txt | ./program > output.txt
```

Comment: This reads the entire `input.txt` file into memory. Be careful if `input.txt` might be large.

Comment: Is there a difference between this and `cat`?

Comment: Which `cat`?  In PowerShell, "cat" is an alias of `Get-Content`, so they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JackO'Connor: No, `Get-Content` sends the lines it reads _one by one_ through the pipeline.

Comment: Interesting to note that the `<` operator is reported "reserved for future use" in PowerShell 6

Comment: It has been that way since PS v1.

Comment: Wow, what an awkward way to do it... If the `<` operator is not currently in use, why not use it for what most people expect it to do =/

Comment: what if the command prompts for a password. can i redirect the password to it?

Comment: @ShahyadSharghi If the command will take input from stdin, this this method will work.  Otherwise no.

Answer (score 33):

If there is someone looking for 'Get-Content' alternative for large files (as me) you can use CMD in PowerShell:

```
cmd.exe /c ".\program < .\input.txt"
```

Or you can use this PowerShell command:

```
Start-Process .\program.exe -RedirectStandardInput .\input.txt -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

It will run the program synchronously in same window. But I was not able to find out how to write result from this command to a variable when I run it in PowerShell script because it always writes data to the console.

EDIT:

To get output from Start-Process you can use option

> -RedirectStandardOutput

for redirecting output to file and then read it from file:

```
Start-Process ".\program.exe" -RedirectStandardInput ".\input.txt" -RedirectStandardOutput ".\temp.txt" -NoNewWindow -Wait
$Result = Get-Content ".\temp.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. This `cmd` command allowed me to redirect file content without new line that Powershell was adding to pipeline.

Answer (score 10):

For output redirection you can use:

```
  command >  filename      Redirect command output to a file (overwrite)

  command >> filename      APPEND into a file

  command 2> filename      Redirect Errors
```

Input redirection works in a different way. For example see this Cmdlet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do:

something like:

```
$proc = Start-Process "my.exe" "exe commandline arguments" -PassThru -wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError "path to error file" -redirectstandardinput "path to a file from where input comes"
```

if you want to know if process errored out, add following code:

$exitCode = $proc.get_ExitCode()

```
if ($exitCode){
    $errItem = Get-Item "path to error file"
    if ($errItem.length -gt 0){
        $errors = Get-Content "path to error file" | Out-String
    }
}
```

I find that this way I do have a better handle on execution of your scripts, when you need to handle external program/process. Otherwise I have encountered situations where script would hang out on some of external process errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this to have standard error and standard out go to the same place (note that in cmd, 2>&1 must be *last*):

get-childitem foo 2>&1 >log

Note that ">" is the same as "| out-file", and by default the encoding is unicode or utf 16.  Also be careful with ">>", because it can mix ascii and unicode in the same text file.  "| add-content" probably works better than ">>".  "| set-content" might be preferable to ">".

There's 6 streams now.  More info:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1

I think all you can do is save to a text file and then read it into a variable after.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PowerShell v7.3.x and `Get-Content` has been aliased to `cat`. To check for your PS do `Get-Command cat`

Since `cat` feels more like a shell thing, I do a `cat content` then `|` (pipe) then the `exe` to which we want to redirect input to.

*Either use `absolute paths` or `invoke from within dir`*

```bash
PS C:\user\working-dir > cat .\input | .\program.exe
```

Attached screen snip
[image: Screen snip]