# How to read a file containing ctrl-Z when stdin is redirected from a file?

Tags: python, windows, end-of-life

I have a line like this in my python script:

```
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

Then I run the script with file redirecting on Windows:

> >> python test.py < binary_file

If binary_file contains `\x1a` (ctrl-Z) that is `EOF` in Windows,  data will only have the string before `\x1a`.  I know this can be fixed with `open("...", "rb")` for a regular file.

How would I handle this for `sys.stdin`?

Comment: Pressing CTRL-Z in a console window closes the input which causes the program to get an end-of-file. However, it's not the actual byte `0x1a` that causes EOF. The value `0x1a` is just a normal byte of data, like any other byte of data.

Comment: On the other hand, you will probably have *other* problems reading binary data from standard input like that on a Windows system. The most important is that the byte sequence `0x0d 0x0a` will be converted to `0x0a` only. That is, carriage-return followed by newline will be converted to newline only (`'\r\n'` -> `'\n'`)

Comment: I have tested files containing 0x1a, the bytes that following 0x1a can not be read into `data'.

Comment: Then it's the console program that reads and checks for this byte, because there is really nothing special with this specific value. A byte of data is a byte of data is a byte of data... But like I said in the other comment, reading binary data from a file not opened in text mode is going to be trouble no matter what, don't do it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised in the least if the pipe/console handler on Windows would stop when there is a `\0x1a` in the input.

Answer (score 3):

My next step would be to try the [fileinput module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) but my gut feeling is that `cmd.exe` (or the code which handles pipes) really processes the stream, looks for `\0x1a` bytes and sends you an EOF.

If that's the case, there is nothing you can do; the OS simply won't let you read past this byte. There is no way to "switch" `stdin` to binary mode since this handle is opened by the runtime or the OS and then passed to Python.

As a workaround, you can try to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) which gives you a real shell (instead of an emulation of bugs creates in the 1980s).

Or try [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). If you're lucky, they didn't reimplement this bug in there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check fileinput module.  As for Powershell, I found redirection operator '<' isn't even suported in versoin1.0.  I might as well change my code.

Comment: PowerShell uses object pipes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell