# Run script from host machine on Docker container with exec

Tags: docker

I do have docker container running and I do quite complex script to run inside container.
The script is located on host machine.
I can't modify Dockerfile
How can I place script file to docker vm to run it with docker exec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can `docker cp` your script, and then you run it, with something like `docker exec -it container_id script`

the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

You can see some examples at
https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/captvty/

extract

`docker exec -it container_id unzip -d ~/Captvty ~/Téléchargements/captvty-2.3.10.zip`

answer Yes to All

and

`docker exec -it container_id rm ~/Téléchargements/captvty-2.3.10.zip`

Comment: docker cp is just solve all my problems, thanks a lot

Comment: Sadly if you use docker-compose then there is no docker-compose cp cmd:/ Any other way to run `docker exec` and provide it shell script from the host?

Comment: if you use docker-compose, you launch containers, so you can still `docker cp` you just have to provide the id or the name of the container. Remember docker-compose is just fig http://www.fig.sh/ bundled into docker since docker.com bought them

Comment: Also checkout `docker exec -i mycontainer bash < mylocal.sh` "This reads the local host script and runs it inside the container. You can do this with other things (like .tgz files piped into tar) - its just using the '-i' to pipe into the container process std input." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578446/running-a-script-inside-a-docker-container-using-shell-script#comment82395122_31578527