# Cannot run sysctl command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, sysctl

I'm trying to make my first dockerfile(I'm new to this), and I need the system to run the command `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` (its an lab env.), but I get the error:

> sysctl: setting key "kernel.randomize_va_space": Read-only file
>   system

Whenever I try to build the dockerfile, any suggestion how to get this  around ?

```
FROM avatao/lesp:ubuntu-14.04

USER root

COPY ./solvable/ /

RUN sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0

VOLUME ["/tmp"]

EXPOSE 2222

WORKDIR /home/user/

USER user

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-Df", "/etc/ssh/sshd_config_user"]
```

Comment: Do you need it during building the image or when the image runs?

Comment: when the image runs

Comment: You can try the [sysarch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21737175/485343) approach. But not from RUN, RUN is executed at build time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since Docker containers share the host system's kernel and its settings, a Docker container usually can't run `sysctl` at all.  (You especially can't disable security-critical settings like this one.)  You can set a limited number of sysctls on a container-local basis with [`docker run --sysctl`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime), but the one you mention isn't one of these.

Furthermore, you also can't force changes like this in a Dockerfile.  A Docker image only contains a filesystem and some associated metadata, and not any running processes or host-system settings.  Even if this `RUN sysctl` worked, if you rebooted your system and then launched a container from the image, that setting would be lost.

Given what you've shown in this Dockerfile – customized Linux kernel settings, no specific application running, an open-ended ssh daemon as the container process – you might consider whether a virtual machine fits your needs better.  You can use a tool like [Packer](https://packer.io/) to reproducibly build a VM image in much the same way a Dockerfile builds a Docker image.  Since a VM *does* have an isolated kernel, you can run that `sysctl` command there and it will work, maybe via normal full-Linux-installation methods like an `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

Comment: Are you sure Docker containers share the host system's kernel and its settings? I set net.core.somaxconn to 65535 on host, however, the container created on the same host still shows 128 for net.core.somaxconn.

Comment: The `docker run` documentation (I fixed the link in my answer) notes that `net.*` sysctls are namespaced, and so they can be set on a per-container basis.

Answer (score 7):

This is expected since docker restricts access to `/proc` and `/sys` (for security). Fundamentally, in order to achieve what you are trying, you need to either give the user `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or run in privileged mode, neither of which is allowed during `build`, see {[issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916)}.

Currently, if you can have those things run after the container is running, then you can use either `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` or `--privileged` flag. Ideally, these aren't things we would do in a production system, but you seem to be running in a lab setup. If doing it at the `run` stage, I would recommend first trying the `--sysctl` flag, but that only supports a subset of command and I'm not sure if it will let you modify kernel settings.

Comment: yeah it's a lab setup(trying to make a setup which the students can connect via ssh and perform the "return to libc" attack).    are those flags needs to be added when u build the docker? (docker build .... --privileged?)

Comment: @neorus unfortunately, the github issue to add privileged type support to `docker build` is still open (open for 6 years) - you can follow along in [issues/1916](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916)

Comment: The issue has been closed. However as mentioned by @David Maze, `net.*` sysctls can only be used on a container-basis, not for images.

Answer (score 0):

Run your container using the following:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged myapp:1.0 /bin/bash
```

Then you will be able to execute your Dockerfile without any problem.

Comment: _If_ you do this, understand it gives the container _all_ capabilities and lifts restrictions enforced by the cgroup controller. It's better to follow the principle of least privilege and use `--cap-add` to give only those capabilities needed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441605/2908724.