# What is difference between privilege flag in docker and using cap-add=ALL?

Tags: docker, security, privileges, docker-in-docker

I want to run docker in docker but without the privilege flag. Ready to give the required capabilities and ready to mount the required volumes from host as well. Just want to understand what the privilege flag does which is not covered by cap-add ALL.

Comment: Can you use a `docker run -v` option to inject host content into the container, without setting any special privilege flags at all?

Comment: I think [Privileged containers and capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425230/privileged-containers-and-capabilities) has an answer for your specific question, with a reference to Docker documentation discussing additional cgroup-related restrictions that `--privileged` removes (along with several comments that you probably don't want a privileged container in any normal use).