# Create docker container with Node.js/NPM preinstalled but no package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am looking for a Docker image that is just some *nix flavor with NPM and Node.js installed.

This image

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

requires that a package.json file is present, and the Docker build uses COPY to copy the package.json file over, and it also looks for a Node.js script to start when the build is run.

...I just need a container to run a shell script using this technique:

```
docker exec mycontainer /path/to/test.sh
```

Which I discovered via:

[Running a script inside a docker container using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578446/running-a-script-inside-a-docker-container-using-shell-script)

I don't need a package.json file or a Node.js start script, all I want is

1. a container image
2. Node.js and NPM installed

Does anyone know if there is an a Docker image for Node.js / NPM that does not require a package.json file? Perhaps I should just use a plain old container image and just add the code to install Node myself?

Comment: Thanks, I just want to run some tests in the container. Turns out I can use the start script of the package.json file to run the bash script in question. But I don't really need that package.json file. The only things I need (1) a container, (2) NPM and node.js installed.

Comment: Added an answer, seems to work for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I tried to make this a simple question, unfortunately nobody could provide a simple answer...until now!

Instead of using this base image:

```
FROM node:5-onbuild
```

We use this instead:

```
FROM node:5
```

I read about onbuild and could not figure out what it's about, but it adds more than I needed for my use case.

the below code is in our Dockerfile

```
# 1. start with this image as a base
FROM node:5

# 2. copy the script from real-life into the container (magic)
COPY script.sh /usr/src/app/ 

# 3. define container entry point which will run our script 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/usr/src/app/script.sh"]
```

you build the docker image like so:

```
docker build -t foo .
```

then you run the image like so, which will "run the entrypoint":

```
docker run -it --rm foo
```

The container stdout should stream to the terminal where you ran `docker run` which is good (am I asking too much?).