# sh: 0: Can't open mysql2sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to convert `.sql` file to `.sqlite`. i got the script from here [link](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh)
 I am trying to execute script like this

```
./mysql2sqlite country.sql | sqlite3 mysqlite3.db
```

but getting error like this

```
bash: ./mysql2sqlite: No such file or directory
```

when I tried like this

```
sh mysql2sqlite country.sql | sqlite3 mysqlite3.db
```

I am getting error as

```
sh: 0: Can't open mysql2sqlite
```

I am not getting script is wrong or the way i am doing is wrong ?
is there any way i can do it.

Comment: you can directly import sql file in sqlite file. open sqlite file in sqlite Reader and click on import, it will show you to import option from sql file.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar i am getting some error as error in importing sql...i tried that way as well for that i need to remove some lines from sql file ..every time it is not easy

Answer (score 0):

At first set terminal same  mysql2sqlite directory path

try chmod 755 mysql2sqlite.sh

then ./mysql2sqlite.sh YourDatabaseName -uYourUserName -pYourPassword | sqlite3 path/NewDatabaseName.sqlite

[here](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh) you can see documentation

## Usage: $ ./mysql2sqlite mysqldump-opts db-name | sqlite3 database.sqlite

## Example: $ ./mysql2sqlite --no-data -u root -pMySecretPassWord myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite