# Using CPIO without a pipeline or with powershell redirection?

Tags: powershell, cpio

Apologies for an ultra-stupid question.

I'm trying to use cpio with powershell, and the redirections are... painful.  I've read through several stackoverflow answers:

https://superuser.com/questions/654574/pipeline-input-to-executable-with-powershell

[Redirecting standard input\output in Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell)

and can't get it to work, but the problem seems to be with the basic invocation of cpio.

For simplicity:

1. I want to create a file with a list of filenames.
2. I want CPIO to use this list instead of using standard input.
3. I want CPIO to create an archive that I name without using standard output.

According to the gnu docs, this should be doable. https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/html_node/Copy_002dout-mode.html#Copy_002dout-mode

```
-F [[user@]host:]archive-file
-O [[user@]host:]archive-file
--file=[[user@]host:]archive-file

    Use the supplied archive-file instead of standard input. Optional user and host specify the user and host names in case of a remote archive.
```

However,

```
$ldclist = get-childitem * -include *out.*
$ldclist.name|%{ "$_" }| out-file -encoding ascii cpiolist
.\cpio.exe -o -O cpiolist >testarc
```

simply doesn't work.  It actually overwrites cpiolist with a blank file (or, depending, "TRAILER!!!").  If I try invoking it from CMD, it seems to be waiting for more inputs (if I hit enter, it says ": Invalid argument")

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I just figured out - the input file, even though this I'm using a Windows port, requires a unix-formatted input file.

Comment: Okay, so I got it to pipeline - have to use a Windows port of the unix "cat" command, then you can do "cat myunixformattedlistoffiles |cpio --create -O testarc".  Still doesn't solve it, but getting closer.

Comment: "invalid argument" appears to be due to it receiving Windows carriage returns instead of non-unix linefeeds (CR/LF instead of LF)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible.  I've given up and created a batch file that does the pipeline redirect, then invoke that via powershell.