# How to pipe Program into PHP (-r) in Windows?

Tags: php, shell

In Windows 7, running php.exe from `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe`, 
I find that the following *prints the PHP usage instructions*.

`echo 4;|php -r`  <-- prints php usage instructions

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25>echo 4;|php -r
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
   php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
```

However, a friend claims that the same command  `echo 4;|php -r`  (or perhaps he means `echo '4;'|php -r` works for him using Linux.

How can I get this behaviour in windows?

**Note** I'm aware of php -r used to run some code passed as a parameter following it, i'm asking about it running a file or accepting stdin.

Comment: What's the point of the `echo 4` part? That seems entirely useless as `php -r` doesn't take any input.

Comment: Is there piping in windows? Last time I checked there wasn't....

Comment: @man0v There is with PowerShell if you want to go down that road.

Comment: @tadman I'll refrain for the time being.

Comment: @tadman he is talking about the default terminal of windows, I can't recall its name. But it doesn't support piping.

Comment: @Naresh You wrote "he is talking about the default terminal of windows, I can't recall its name. But it doesn't support piping." <-- what are you talking about.. Windows has such a thing as CMD.EXE which absolutely supports pipes! It's standard usage!

Comment: @Naresh There's `cmd.exe` which is barely better than DOS 1.0. PowerShell has been shipping with Windows for about ten years, though.

Comment: @tadman  cmd.exe supports pipes and i'm sure I can demonstrate the same probelm in powershell too if you prefer

Comment: oh, I thought PowerShell was some third party SW, my bad.

Comment: @tadman php -r  Does take input  `php -r "4;"`

Comment: @barlop This appears to be an XY Problem. What's the motivation between trying to pipe here when piping does nothing useful?

Comment: @tadman I want to run php -r on a file,(php does -r lets the input run without php tags), and `php -r -f aa.php` doesn't work either (the -r has no effect)

Comment: @barlop There's a difference between "takes input" as in *requires an argument* and "takes input" as in *reads from STDIN*. The first one requires command-line interpolation, which in bash is `php -r \`echo 4\``. The second is like `echo 4 | php -r` but which is entirely different.

Comment: @tadman I agree they're different but apparently both work in linux so php in linux supports both.

Comment: When I do `echo 4 | php -r` it errors out with the usage information because `-r` *requires an argument*. It's not valid, it doesn't work.

Comment: @tadman What OS are you using tadman to test that ? As I said.  I have a friend with linux that said it worked for him

Comment: Tested on both Ubuntu (Linux) and macOS. If it "worked" you'll have to be more specific about what it did because I can't see that command doing anything useful.

Comment: did't work for me in Ubuntu 14... same usage error

Comment: @Naresh ok thanks, I guess i had wrong info from the friend that said it worked for them

Comment: @man0v Sideline: *both* cmd.exe ( https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html ) and PS ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell ) support basic STDOUT-STDIN pipes.

Comment: I think your friend is misrepresenting what actually happened or isn't conveying what they actually did. `echo 4; | php -r` is a syntax error at the shell level. `echo 4 | php -r` does nothing useful.

Comment: @tadman  Does `echo 4 | php -r`  for you in linux, print nothing or print usage info? (there is a big difference there because if it prints nothing, it works and if it prints usage info it doesn't)

Comment: @barlop It prints usage info because `-r` requires an argument that isn't given.

Comment: @tadman thanks for testing, and yes now we have established that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few points of confusion here, so I'll do my best to itemize what's wrong.

First, the original command can't work on Linux/POSIX shell because it's not valid:

```
echo 4; | php -r
```

Where `;` has significant meaning, it's a command separator, and a command can't begin with `|`.

Fixing this, you get:

```
echo '4;' | php -r
```

Where that is at least valid as far as the shell is concerned, but it's still not enough for PHP to deal with. The `-r` argument requires a second term, `code`, which is the code to be evaluated. This needs to be supplied inline, not externally as you usually would.

Specifically the `-r` flag does not mean "run the input file as if it has `<?php ... ?>` surrounding it" but instead it means "run this bit of code in PHP mode".

For example:

```
echo '4;' | php
```

Technically works, but it's not evaluated as PHP code, so it's pointless.

The version that does work in POSIX shell is this:

```
php -r `echo '4;'`
```

Where that inlines the output of `echo '4;'` into the command-line argument itself. I'm not sure Windows can do that without PowerShell involved.

The `-r` flag is intended for quick little snippets like:

```
php -r 'echo 5 * 9;'
```

Where that prints `45` as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I see that -r doesn't accept stdin, and if you do pass a file with -f, it won't apply -r to it, and the info I had from the friend was incorrect. Though one could use xargs

Comment: @barlop `xargs` is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: Why a can of worms?

Comment: Let's tackle one problem at a time per question. If you have another related to `xargs` you can open that up independently.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo 4 | php -r
```

instead of terminating echo 4 and piping nothing into php.

Not that it should matter, "-r" means nothing to php. Nor does 4 (apart from rhyming).

Comment: The `-r` flag requires an argument, which in this case is omitted. Also STDIN is apparently ignored in `-r` mode.

Comment: @tadman so why has gerard written it with STDIN with -r as if it's not ignored? is gerard incorrect?  What OS have you tested this in tadman?  And Gerard, what OS have you tested this in?

Comment: I can't test it, i have currently no Windows.  Piping does work in Windows CMD, but php needs a php command, and I've never seen the command "4" or "4;" in php.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille In the original question it's `echo 4; | php -r` which I think is a mangling of `php -r '4;'` which actually is valid PHP code. On Linux `;` is a command separator, though, so running that you get "syntax error near unexpected token `|`".

Comment: @barlop  thanks for testing, it's what I thought.  Try piping something sensible to php, like " echo "<?php  phpinfo(); ?> | php"

Comment: @tadman, pleas enlighten me, what does "4;" do in Windows php?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  You haven't understood the question. the -r argument means no php tags needed.  So a file with just `4;` in php  would do nothing, not give an error.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I don't think it doesn't do anything there, either. This whole thing is a red herring.

Comment: @barlop The argument is documented as `-r <code>` which means `code` is required. Without any code it errors out with usage info because the argument is wrong.

Comment: @tadman doing nothing means it worked.  Giving usage info means it didn't work. I have not given any red herrings. This answer was untested and when tested, failed.

Comment: @barlop I think we've firmly established that the original `echo 4; | php -r` cannot possibly work for two specific reasons: `;` is a special character to bash, so that's wrong, and `-r` requires an argument, so that's wrong as well. That it doesn't work in Windows is a consequence of both those things.

Comment: @tadman   `;` is not special in cmd it gets passed literally. For linux it'd be echo '4;' but php -r only takes a file and not stdin so it doesn't work. Windows has no issue with the semicolon. Linux does and needs quotes.

Comment: This does work on Linux:  "echo "print 'boe';" | php"

Comment: @barlop `php -r` is one of the few arguments that does not take a file. It *must* have the code supplied immediately following the `-r` argument. Note how the `-r` usage is documented on its own line in the usage because of how unusual it is.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  `echo asdf|php` also works but it's not what I was asking about.. Maybe I should delete my question 'cos it was based on misinformation

Comment: @tadman If you want you can write an answer explaining that it's not possible and that -r  doesn't accept stdin, and if you do pass a file with -f, it won't apply -r to it, and the info I had from the friend was incorrect. (The ; was irrelevant in the windows case because windows doesn't consider the ; to be special.. the linux equivalent quoting the ; didn't work for the above mentioned reason)