# Docker: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile

I have the following warning when I log in to my registry during a continuous integration (CI) process:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
```

Should I just replace `--password` with `--password-stdin`?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

According to [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#provide-a-password-using-stdin) documentation:

> To run the docker login command non-interactively, you can set the
>   `--password-stdin` flag to provide a password through STDIN. Using
>   STDIN prevents the password from ending up in the shell’s history, or
>   log-files.

The following examples read a password from a file, and passes it to the docker login command using STDIN:

```
$ cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

or

```
$ docker login --username foo --password-stdin < ~/my_password
```

The following example reads a password from a variable, and passes it to the docker login command using STDIN:

```
$ echo "$MY_PASSWORD" | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. Now another question, why would `--password` would end up in shell history or log files? We use a CI process for release our docker image so there is no history and I can't see anything in the log after doing the command.

Comment: It's assuming you typed it yourself, not a CI environment.

Comment: why wouldn't this work? (it doesn't, but I don't understand why since I'm not very good with bash): docker login --username foo --password-stdin < "$MY_PASSWORD"

Comment: @Thomas `command < FILENAME` expression means `Accept input from a file`. You cannot use it for a variable.

Comment: The echo avoids the warning message but not the security issue docker is trying to warn you about.  You'll still have the password available in the process listing and potentially bash history.

Comment: `echo` in bash does not really run the command but it is directly passed in.

Comment: Another pro tip is that prefixing your command with a space usually leaves the command out of history.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa When command is run in shell its history is stored, we can see the latest commands we ran by using arrow up key,, so there is a chance that pwd will be visible. But if we pass the password using stdin we won't be typing pwd rather passing it to the linked command via pipe or some other operator. So if we do key up we won't see pwd at all.

Comment: To work with AWS: `aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin REPO_URI`

Comment: echo "$MY_PASSWORD" | docker login --username foo --password-stdin

Not working in @gitlab ci

Comment: If MY_USERNAME and MY_PASSWORD are env variables, then this won't leave crumbs all over your history: `env | grep "^MY_PASSWORD=" | cut -d= -f2 | docker login -u "$MY_USERNAME" --password-stdin`

Comment: @vmallet That's clever. Small caveat that `cut` will split on every occurrence of the delimiter so you might want `cut -d= -f2-` to include all fields after the first occurrence if your password includes another `=`.

Comment: This answer, while useful, evaded OP's question: They have the password on-hand, not in a file. If I'm working with C#, perhaps I can create an env var from C# code, then pass that env var? Tossing it in a file is np for someone manually doing this, but most people are probably using scripts.

Comment: @vmallet can you explain how your solution works and why doesn't it leave crumbs? Thanks!

Comment: @deltakroneker with `echo $MY_PASSWORD`, the shell does the `$MYPASSWORD` substitution and then runs the command, in this case `echo the-actual-passw0rd`. The problem there is that while it's running, `ps -ef` will reveal the password; and depending on where this is done, this might end up in your shell history. With the `env | ...` solution, the password never gets in the hands of the shell, it only ever goes through pipes between all the processes involved until it reaches `docker`. So no `ps -ef` or history will ever reveal the password.

Answer (score 19):

The same `echo` command on a Windows based system (or when running in an Azure Pipelines task based on *vs2017-win2016*) does also output an additional **newline**.

A workaround for this to use `set /p`, see also [question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line).

The full command will be like:
`echo | set /p="my_password" | docker login --username foo --password-stdin`

Comment: Pleae note the username is not same as your email address. Check your profile on Docker Hub and provide the username specified there.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 solution using powershell:

Use Notepad to create a one line text file with your password. The file was named "password1.txt" for the command line below to work.
Save this file in the folder you are using in powershell (...typically C:\Users\Your_Username ).

```
Get-Content password1.txt | docker login --username my_username --password-stdin
```

Refer:
[Redirecting standard input\output in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell/11788475)

Answer (score 3):

Setup in github actions:

```
echo ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }} | docker login --username ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} --password-stdin
```

Comment: Still gives `WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/runner/.docker/config.json.`

Comment: At the end add "docker logout" in your github actions to delete the password of config.json

Answer (score 2):

And with Windows batch (if not using PowerShell) :

```
type password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning one commonly gets using AWS. If this is the case, another solution to the problem could be not explicitly running the command so that it gets stored in the history. To do this, one could use (with aws2)

```
eval $(aws2 ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

Even though you will still see the warning, the explicit docker command containing the key/password is not stored in the bash history. If unconvinced, try running the `history` command to see for yourself.

Comment: This still outputs the same warning. Additionally, if you've run `set -v` or `set -x` (useful for debugging), the entire command being `eval`d will be output. This results in the token/password used saved in your logs.

Comment: @CoatedMoose, I'd avoid `-v` or `-x` in production setups in general.

Comment: In general, sure. In particular, I ran into this issue in a deployment script. IMO, perfectly reasonable to output progress throughout a deployment script to track which part of a deployment script is in-progress/hung/failing.

Answer (score 1):

For AWS CLI users receiving this warning when logging in to ECR, the recommended authentication mechanism received [an update](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/735) (since version 1.17.10) to include a command to address this warning.

Before:

```bash
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

After:

```bash
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_REGISTRY_URL
```