# Bypassing the --password-stdin warning (docker)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, aws-ecr, windows-server-2019

Another day, another problem with docker.
I have a Windows server 2019, docker version 18.09.03 and I want to get my images to ECR.

For certain reasons, I can't have the warning docker : WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted
My deployment tool considers it as an error and thus, doesn't deploy. I have therefore been looking how to use --password-stdin in the "correct" manner. Which isn't going very well.

Here is the Powershell script I am using right now.

```
#First step to create the file
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | Out-File -FilePath FILEPATH 
#Second step to filter the file and just get the password.
-split @(Get-Content -Path FILEPATH) |Select-Object -Index 5 | Out-File -FilePath FILEPATH

#Get authorized but stdin warning?? 
cat FILEPATH | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://NUMBER.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I am passing the password into a file then stdin from it, it works but it returns the warning.

I have tried that comment too (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2875#issuecomment-433565983) but it doesn't accept the flags neither. I do

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 --password-stdin and Unknown options: --password-stdin
aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --print-password-only
--print-password-only is unknows as well)
```

I am FULLY starting to get annoyed and frustrated by now. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your exit code is non zero? I am using `docker login -u ... -p ...` and getting the warning, but the exit code is 0 and the scripts continue normally.

Comment: Technically, the exit code is 0 yes :). However, the CI Tool for whatever reason picks up the warning as a 1 and returns an error...

Comment: Well then, that's a CI tool problem....  In any case, if you just want to progress beyond that point and fix it later, you can ignore its output for now (`> /dev/null 2&>1`) and solve it later. And if you are at the "later" stage, and want to fix now and use STDIN password, I suggest you follow what the warning tells you and implement [credentials helper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers) - I am personally not using it, I see no need and in any case - don't be discouraged, docker is super helpful once you iron out these issues.

Comment: I have done a previous Ps script to force the exit code to be 1, but as you said, it is a CI tool problem mostly... I will try the Credentials Store, however, first time using it so I need to wrap my mind around it. thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 2):

Use --password-stdin by providing the password via stdin like so:

```
echo <my_password> | docker login -u <username> --password-stdin
```

Or, if fetching the password from a file, like so:

```
cat <my_file> | docker login -u <username> --password-stdin
```

Comment: This answer appears to be identical to the previous answer.

Comment: No, note that the previous answer is buggy: the -p parameter does not take std input and the parameter is piped to docker login (the previous answer describes that there needs to be a <password> attached, which is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

In order to login without any warning one could try **--password-stdin**  but it is important to remember that the password need to be **provided by stdin** in this case. So `--password-stdin <my-pwd>` won't work. 
One could try

```
echo <my-pwd> | docker login <registry-name> -u <username> -p <password>
```

or the following could be done

```
cat ~/my-pwd.txt | docker login <registry-name> -u <username> -p <password>
```

Incase more information refer to the question : [Docker: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489359/docker-using-password-via-the-cli-is-insecure-use-password-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Could just redirect stderr, special bonus using a gcloud auth token.

`docker login https://us.grc.io -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin <<< $(gcloud auth print-access-token --quiet) 2>/dev/null`

> Login Succeeded