# Issue with Docker Login with AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I'm following an aws tutorial to deploy a simple application using containers on aws. I'm trying to connect to AWS's ECR using docker and i get a warning message which doesnt allow me to login.

I'm brand new to the world of docker, containers and aws. I was going through aws tutorials to deploy a simple nodejs application using docker containers into aws per the following instructions:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/break-monolith-app-microservices-ecs-docker-ec2/module-one/

Per instructions, i've installed docker, AWS CLI and created a AWS ECR for docker to access. I've basically got till the following step:
**Step 4 Build and Push the docker image - Point 2 - getting login**

As per point 2, i copy pasted the login details (docker login -u AWS -p ) and ran it and i got the following warning message which isnt allowing me to login or push the docker image to ECR. I tried to research online a lot on what to change. There are lots of articles mentioning the issue but no clear direction as to what exactly to do. I'm not exactly sure where in the command i should use --password-stdin. I've also tried what was provided in the following link [[Docker: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489359/docker-using-password-via-the-cli-is-insecure-use-password-stdin]) but that didnt work either

Expected result:
Login succeeded

Actual result:
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489359/docker-using-password-via-the-cli-is-insecure-use-password-stdin)

Comment: This is a very silly question - In the link above, is the username, same as the docker id we use to login to the docker hub web portal or is it something else?

Comment: The ECR login is in fact successful when you do this.  (Try `docker pull` something from your ECR repo.)  The warning is discussed in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

the warning is fine. have you verified whether the docker push/pull is working ?