# aws ecr saying "Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device" after copied cmd from "Amazon Container Services"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to set up docker image of amazon ECR on `ubuntu18.04` machine of AWS,using commands provided by `view push commands` of `Amazon Container Services`
[image: view push commands of amazon container services]

,please note i have already set up `docker` on my `ubuntu18.04` and also output of `docker -v` is as below

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-143:~$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.7, build 7141c199a2
```

When i execute the command provided by amazon container services on aws cli on ubuntu18.04 i get error as
    Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

The command which i am using is

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 8233251134332.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/gatling-lots
```

please note i have successfully configured awscli and i can see the
detailed  from `aws s3 ls`

Here is detailed error log

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-143:~$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-   
east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 
823443336.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gatling-lots
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...]      
[parameters]
 To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws <command> help
aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

 batch-check-layer-availability           | batch-delete-image                      
 batch-get-image                          | complete-layer-upload                   
create-repository                        | delete-lifecycle-policy                 
delete-repository                        | delete-repository-policy                
 describe-images                          | describe-repositories                   
 get-authorization-token                  | get-download-url-for-layer              
 get-lifecycle-policy                     | get-lifecycle-policy-preview            
 get-repository-policy                    | initiate-layer-upload                   
 list-images                              | put-image                               
 put-lifecycle-policy                     | set-repository-policy                   
 start-lifecycle-policy-preview           | upload-layer-part                       
 get-login                                | help                                    
 Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

output of

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-143:~$ (aws ecr get-login --no-include-email  --region us-east-2)

docker login -u AWS -p 

MzQxL2c0Yks4RjVxeDg9IiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjIiLCJ0eXBlIjoiREFUQV9LRVkiLCJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoxNTgzNjgzNDY5fQ== https://825251119036.dkr.ecr.us- east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: seems like you are using `awscliv1`, while the above command is for `awscliv2`, check your awscli version, or you can try `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)`

Comment: @Adiii i have added the content of your question in the question above,it says access denied,what can be the casue i can see the output of aws s3 ls

Comment: you have only access to s3, you need to request to your AWS account admin to allow to get `GetAuthorizationToken` you need `  "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",` this permission. for detail https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html

Comment: @Adiii now i am getting output for ```$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)``` ,as i have update din teh question above but still my problem. not solved i.e. i am getting ```Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device``` for aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 8233251134332.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/gatling-lots

Comment: you need to add `$` or you can run the ouput command and then you will get login. seems like you miss `$` sign. try with `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email  --region us-east-2)`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The problem is not aws but docker. The solution is on docker to use the -p parameter, and wrap the aws login call to the -p parameter as such:

```
docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region the-region-you-are-in) xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.the-region-you-are-in.amazonaws.com
```

And this requires AWS CLI version 2.

Comment: this may not be the safest method as mentioned here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4962#issuecomment-591266185

Comment: This should not be used if there's another alternative. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51518255/5640649

Comment: this didn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.10, but this did: `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Yes, There could be multiple reasons like aws command version. But now since most environment updated to V2, reason could be docker. For me it was docker issue with default user not able to access docker. Adding the user worked the login command also.

Answer (score 69):

`docker login` prints this error message when you use `--password-stdin`, but don't actually send a password to the command's stdin.

For example:

```
$ echo "" | docker login --password-stdin --username jorendorff
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Therefore, almost any kind of problem with the command before the `|` pipe symbol will result in this unhelpful error message.

Comment: For me it aws cli failing with bad access keys that caused the error `aws ecr get-login-password [snip] | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin`

Comment: Yes, great find!

Answer (score 32):

it took me forever to figure out that the issue was that I forgot to run `aws configure` and enter the right details. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 13):

You need to install AWS CLI version 2.
Follow the instructions in this [Installing or updating the latest version of the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html#cliv2-mac-install-confirm)

Answer (score 8):

This command does the trick in bash and linux at 2020/10/06:

`linux@host:~$ $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)`

That's because

`$ aws ecr get-login --no-include-email`

Gives the following output:

`docker login -u AWS -p xxxxxxxxxxxxx== https://xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: This solution works with AWS CLI Version 1.X. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/welcome-versions.html for more details on the differences and how to update to AWS CLI Version 2.X.

Comment: This is the only answer that I could get to work on a Raspberry Pi Zero with AWS CLI 1.x.

Answer (score 7):

Devin's answer is correct.

But there is one more way.
The updated version of docker requires this parameter `--password-stdin`.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <YOUR_REGION> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: You mean the way that the question is about not working? Because the fact that this complains about "non TTY device" is precisely the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is answered already, but, this was my experience.

This didn't work for me initially.

`aws ecr get-login-password --region <your-region>| docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <your-container>`

I had the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` saved under variables in GitLab.

**But the solution was to uncheck the `Protected` flag from the variables saved on GitLab. I don't know how secure this approach is, but, it did work for me.**

I hope this would help someone one day.

Answer (score 5):

Below steps are resolve that issue.

```
$curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install

$aws --version

aws-cli/2.0.30 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.14.181-142.260.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/2.0.0dev34

$aws ecr get-login-password --region your_region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin Account_ID.dkr.ecr.your_region.amazonaws.com
```

Replace your `Account ID` and `Region`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Atlassian Bamboo, and logging into AWS ECR from an SSH task in a build plan.

I could not run `aws configure` because of insufficient permissions.

So I solved this by setting the AWS credential variables and then the docker login as proposed by one of the other answers:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<value>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<value>
docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region <region>) <accountid>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` can be created in your AWS profile, Security Credentials section.

Hope this helps someone, and a future me when I forget and come back to find help.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember you cannot log into partitioned regions (`cn-*` or `gov`) while using a non-partitioned AWS profile. Add `--profile foo` to specify a profile with your designated region.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize your EC2 machine to access AWS services either by

- running  aws configure and providing the right details
  OR
- Give your EC2 machine a role to enable it access ECR

Also if you run your docker commands with sudo, then add sudo before the docker command as shown below

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 8233251134332.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/gatling-lots
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone.

I tried everything until I removed hyphens from my aws account id. If your right click on your username, aws shows your account id like this:

`6897-6070-0765`

If you put that into the command, it won't work. It works without the dashes:

```
sudo aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 689760700765.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add "sudo" before docker:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | sudo docker login
   --username AWS --password-stdin 8233251134332.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/gatling-lots
```

Comment: gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the command the profile that your sso is saved under.

Example, run

```
aws configure list-profiles
cat ~/.aws/credentials
```

Then use that profile when you make calls:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 --profile saml
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04
I have followed the below commands and it works for me.

1). Retrieve an authentication token and authenticate your Docker client to your registry.

aws ecr-public get-login-password --region <your_region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <your_repo_URI>

2). sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

3). aws ecr-public get-login-password --region <your_region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <your_repo_URI>

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add ECR related policy in my AWS IAM.
To add a policy follow these [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found is AWS CLI v1 vs AWS CLI v2. I resolved this by uninstalling v1 and installing AWS CLI v2.

Comment: Upgrading the aws cli and using --profile for the correct account worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

No worries in this case. Just type 'aws configure' in your terminal and paste the security credentials such as 'aws_access_key_id' and 'aws_secret_access_key'and then type the region of the repository and the output format as 'json'.

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All of the above did not work for me on a windows OS. However, windows (10) was suggesting updates. I applied the **Update & Restart** and when I executed the login command

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region **your_region_code** | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin **numeric-account-id**.dkr.ecr.**your-region-code**.amazonaws.com*
```

Everything worked again normally.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Ubuntu 18.04 after my AWS CLI was automatically updated.

I solved it by reverting it back to the previous version using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install awscli=1.14.44-1ubuntu1 -V
```

Comment: I am having same issue
aws-cli/1.18.69 Python/3.6.9 Linux/5.4.0-1089-azure botocore/1.16.19
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086

aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com

An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

I am using Jenkins Pipeline. Any Idea how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error after re-starting Docker.

It was solved when I did `docker login` initially.

Then `aws ecr get-login-password --region <your_region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <your_uri>/<your_image>` command worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is common having used `aws configure` to input you temporary aws credentials and having used either `aws configure set aws_session_token <session_token>` or directly pasting the token in the  `~/.aws/credentials file`.

It may initially arise after a docker image build and docker fails to push the image with a `Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err:` error.

On trying to update the docker credentials which are typically stored in `~/.docker/config.json`, using `aws ecr get-login-password --region <your-region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  <accountID>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` you will be faced with a  `An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is expired Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device` error.

Having uderstood the base scenario, here are the step I recommend to solve it:

1. In the amazon web portal, on the page with Management cosole |
   Command line or programmatic access, refresh the page and click on
   Command line or programmatic access.
2. In your CLI:

- `rm -rf ~/.aws`
- `rm -rf ~/.docker/config.json`
- `aws configure` - at this point, paste in the Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, your region and output as json(These details should be acquired from the refreshed console access credentials page).
- `aws configure set aws_session_token "<token-goes-here>"` - **IMPORTANT:** The new session token **must** be pasted here.

3. You can go on to now run:
    `aws ecr get-login-password --region <your-region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`

And you're done, all should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was related to log in again with `saml2aws`

```
saml2aws login --force

aws --profile YOUR_AWS_PROFILE sts get-caller-identity
```

then try to login again AWS with Docker

```
aws --profile YOUR_AWS_PROFILE ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update, 2023-07-18

**Platform**: `Arch Linux amd64 (6.4.3-arch1-2)`

I had to downgrade from `2.13.1` to `2.12.1` to get rid of this error (same as OP).

Answer (score 0):

For AWS Cloudshell users having this issue, problem is with docker access. Default user will not have access to docker since it was installed as sudo. And default user only have access to aws resources. If you run the command as sudo you will get the access related issue like setup aws account with aws configure. So the solution is to make the cloud shell user get docker access. Following commands could be useful for this.

```html
# Add docker group, mostly it will be there, so it will be ignored
sudo groupadd docker
# Add cloudshell-user to the group
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
# Update changes
newgrp docker
```

Now try running the docker login to ecr

Answer (score -1):

This answer is for similar error getting for github actions. Please try this and let me know if this works

````
- name: Docker login
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}```
````