# Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device while trying to connect Docker to ECS repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to push a local docker image into the ECS repository I created.

Following this link [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html)

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com --profile loadeo
```

Errors:

```
unknown flag: --profile
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

I also referred to the stack overflow question on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583847/aws-ecr-saying-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device-after).
Here the accepted answer is to have awscli version two.
I feel I have version 2 of cli

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.19 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev23
```

In the above command if I don't use --profile I get the error.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com



 Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

What is that I am missing here? Could any one please help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need to use [aws named profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) of your configuration, then you can use [aws cli to list the profiles](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/list.html)

```sh
aws configure list
```

when you located the profile, use it in conjunction with [get-login-password](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html)

```sh
aws ecr get-login-password \
  --region <region> \
  --profile <profile> \
| docker login \
  --username AWS \
  --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was really elementary of me to not know the placing of --profile

Comment: @sumanthshetty: i am glad it helped you! :)