# How to use the authorization token obtained from AWS ECR for performing a docker pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

How to use the authorization token obtained from AWS ECR for performing a docker pull

The following call fetches you the TOKEN

> ```
> TOKEN=$(aws ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken')
> ```

How to pass this token information to pull a private docker image in AWS ECR

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html

> To obtain an authorization token, you must use the
> GetAuthorizationToken API operation to retrieve a base64-encoded
> authorization token containing the username AWS and an encoded
> password

So the auth token contains the user and password as a base64 encode string. That you can then use to login to the private repo using `docker login`.
The command would be something like this:
`docker login --username userNameFromToken --password passwordFromToken aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com`

However I would recommend using the [get-login-password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html) cli to simplify that for you.

Again from the same docs all you have to do is this:

`aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com`

And you should have docker cli logged in.

And then you can just pull using a command like `docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/your-repo-name:tag`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using authorization token, this might work for you:

```
docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-authorization-token --profile *profileName* --region *your-region* --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 --decode | cut -c 5- ) ****.dkr.ecr.**-****-*.amazonaws.com
```

What i am doing with this is getting the authorization token, doing a base64 decode on it and removing the first 4 characters from it since the base64 decoded string is in the form of username(AWS):encoded_password. So we are removing *AWS:* using the cut command.

Reference: [aws ecr saying "Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device" after copied cmd from "Amazon Container Services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583847/aws-ecr-saying-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device-after)