# ECR image push fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push a new image to my repository, and I get a wierd fail.

I did this action in the past from the same user with the same permissions, but it keeps failing. Any idea why?

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/l4s5v1w9
```

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583847/aws-ecr-saying-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device-after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aws ecr saying "Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device" after copied cmd from "Amazon Container Services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583847/aws-ecr-saying-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device-after)