# Odd behavior from AWS Elastic Container Registry in us-east-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I'm having a strange problem pulling an image from ECR into my EC2 instances. This command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2
```

times out. This has been working for months (I'm familiar with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583847/aws-ecr-saying-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device-after) that describes how to trouble-shoot logging into ECR, and that's not the problem).

Here's what weird:

1. `get-login-password` works successfully from my local machine when I'm pushing to or pulling a container from ECR, but fails when I want to try to pull that image from ECR to an EC2 instance (same AWS credentials are used).
2. But if I use a different region (us-east-1 or us-west-1), a password is returned.

- I'm using version 2.7.7 of the aws CLI on my EC2 instance and 2.5.6 on my local machine (a mac).
- I have admin privileges on AWS.
- `aws sts-caller-identity` returns successfully, so my credentials are valid.
- As far as I know, nothing has changed in w/r/t the EC2 instances (I'm the admin)
- I turned on debug - here's the relevant stack trace:

> 2022-12-15 19:53:23,884 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (3): api.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443
> 2022-12-15 19:56:24,064 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG -  Exception received when sending HTTP request
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
> File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
> File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
> socket.timeout: timed out

My assumption would be that there's an issue with the ECR service in `us-east-2` except that I can login and push or pull containers from my local machine but not from my EC2 instances.

Comment: It sounds like the EC2 instance isn't able to talk to the `us-east-2` ECR endpoint. Your instance doesn't have internet connectivity, right?

Comment: @paolo That seems to be it, but I don't understand why - it can talk to the `us-east-1` and `us-west-1` ECR endpoints. I don't restrict any outbound traffic.

Comment: You must have VPC endpoint deployed in those regions, but not in `us-east-2`