# helm registry login --password-stdin in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, kubernetes-helm, cicd, azure-acr

I am trying to login to my private ACR using azure DevOps pipeline.

I tried it this way:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscriptionForACR)
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $password = az acr credential show -n $(azureAcrName) --query passwords[0].value
      helm registry login $(azureContainerRegistry) --username $(azureAcrUserName) --password $password
```

which works, but there is a warning when I run the pipeline:

**"WARNING: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin."**

I would like to avoid the warning, so I tried many variant of this, but no success:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscriptionForACR)
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $password = az acr credential show -n $(azureAcrName) --query passwords[0].value
      echo $password | helm registry login $(azureContainerRegistry) --username $(azureAcrName) --password-stdin
```

It always end up with:

Error: Get "https://azureacr.azurecr.io/v2/": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.

I am using new helm 3.8.0

Is there a way to do it with --password-stdin?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the `$password value` as an ***Environment Variable*** in Azure Devops , the same way you are doing for the `ACR username` and other values and then use `echo` command .

**Example:**

First ***get the password for the ACR using the below command*** and then ***store it in Environment Variable `registryPassword`*** .

```
az acr credential show -n $(azureAcrName) --query passwords[0].value
```

---

**Then use the below to login:**

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscriptionForACR)
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
    echo $(registryPassword) | helm registry login $(azureContainerRegistry) --username $(azureAcrName) --password-stdin
```

For more information you can refer this ***[`Blog`](https://www.abhith.net/blog/azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline-involving-helm-3-acr-aks/)*** by ***Abhith Rajan*** or
this ***[`SO thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489359/docker-using-password-via-the-cli-is-insecure-use-password-stdin)***.