# Running Helm in my Pipeline keeps asking me to login

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have a pipeline where I need to run some helm commands in order to deploy something. I run `az login` and then I run my `az aks get-credentials`. After that, if I try to run `helm install` or even `kubectl get all`, it keeps asking for authentication through a web browser. I don't understand what I am doing wrong if I can do this from a VM.

```
echo "Getting credentials to AKS cluster: akstest1"
az aks get-credentials -g rgtest1 -n akstest1 --overwrite-existing

echo "Container Registry Login to $(acrurl)"
helm registry login $(acrurl) --username $(acruser) --password $(acrtoken)

echo "Running helm uninstall"
helm delete nfs --kubeconfig /home/AzDevOps/.kube/config
```

Here is the output of my pipeline

> /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc
> /agent/_work/_temp/08e2b7e1-4985-4d94-9809-b8cf0d1a2d5d.sh
> /agent/_work/_temp/08e2b7e1-4985-4d94-9809-b8cf0d1a2d5d.sh: line 1:
> Getting credentials to AKS cluster: ${{ parameters.clusterName }}: bad
> substitution WARNING: Merged "akstest1" as current
> context in /home/AzDevOps/.kube/config
>
> Container Registry Login to crviyatrsasptvaldecc1.azurecr.io
>
> WARNING: Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin.
>
> Login Succeeded
>
> Running helm uninstall
>
> To sign in, use a web browser to open the page
> https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code A9EVL8AVJ to
> authenticate.
>
> ##[error]The operation was canceled. Finishing: nfs

Comment: This seems like it might fit better on another site like [devops.se]; it seems more about deployment mechanics than programming _per se_.

Comment: Upgrade your helm and kubectl version to the latest level. See this [article](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5788). You're likely bumping into the same problem; versions are incompatible with each other. Refer to this version [doc](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/version_skew/) from helm and also check these [article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70860324/helm-registry-login-password-stdin-in-azure-devops-pipeline) and [article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489359/docker-using-password-via-the-cli-is-insecure-use-password-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which will add the registry + log you in in one step:

```
helm repo add --username=$(acruser) --password=$(acrtoken) my-repo-name $(acrurl)
```