# Import MySQL Dump with Ansible

Tags: mysql, powershell, ansible, openstack, azure-powershell

So im trying to import a MySQL dump that contains two databases with Ansible on a Windows box. 
The Ansible playbook should be correct.

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Import DB
    win_command: 'mysql -uroot -p12345678910 -hlocalhost < "C:\sql\dump.sql"'
    args:
      chdir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\
```

On the windows box if I open CMD and run
`cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\` and then `'mysql -uroot -p12345678910 -hlocalhost < "C:\sql\dump.sql"'` it works perfectly.

Im getting a giant error. What am I doing wrong?

Im able to check the DB with a very similar Playbook:

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Check DB
    win_command: 'mysql -uroot -p12345678910  -e "SHOW DATABASES;"'
    args:
      chdir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be input redirection. Perhaps you can try something like:

```
win_command: 'Get-Content C:\sql\dump.sql | mysql -uroot -p12345678910 -hlocalhost'
```

See [Redirecting standard input\output in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell/11788475)