# Windows terminal not recognizing "<" operator for file redirection

Tags: powershell, operators, windows-terminal

I am trying to write a program where I have to use file redirection to cin text from another text file.  I'm seeing that I should be able to use .\a.exe < inputFile.txt, but for whatever reason my windows terminal does not recognize "<".  This is the error I got :

```
At line:1 char:14
+ .\a.exe 1000 <input1L.txt
+              ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

I don't know why it's not recognizing it and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: That looks like a PowerShell error message, not a "normal" command-prompt ("DOS prompt") error message.

Comment: The file redirection symbol is '>'. Try change in it.

Comment: @DiegoBascans That re-directs output to a file. Anyway, this is a dupe.

Comment: @DiegoBascans `<` is commonly used for *input* redirection, to redirect standard input from a file. Except in PowerShell, apparently.

Comment: Also, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, the `<` operator isn't implemented, but in practice you can work around this by piping (`|`) instead.

In your example, instead of this:

```
.\a.exe 1000 <input1L.txt
```

You should be able to write this:

```
Get-Content input1L.txt | .\a.exe 1000
```

(presuming your `.\a.exe` accepts standard input).