# How to feed file data to an exe (executable) file in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, exe, executable, equivalent

I had compiled a cpp (c++) file, which generated an executable (`a.exe` file) in Windows. 
In Linux, `a.out` file would be generated. 
I want to run the executable but I do not want to manually enter the inputs that the executable needs. 
Hence, I aim to feed the inputs from a saved file to the executable.

For example, the bash equivalent would be

```
$ ./a.out < testfile
```

In Windows (Windows Powershell / pwsh), I want to run my `a.exe` instead of `a.out`. 
The `testfile` here contains some text data to feed to the executable (which is not important), for example:

```
3
123
1234
12344
```

**I just want to feed the executable, some input from an existing file.**
How do I do it?

Comment: Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell?force_isolation=true

Comment: In short: PowerShell has _no_ `<` operator for providing data from a file to a program via stdin and instead requires the use of `Get-Content` in a pipeline. That is, instead of `someProgram <file`  use `Get-Content file | someProgram`, but note that this only works with _text_ files as of PowerShell 7..3.4, and involves encoding their content based on the value of `$OutputEncoding`. If you need raw byte support, you must call via the platform-native shell, namely `cmd /c 'someProgram <file'` on Windows, and `sh -c 'someProgram < file'` on Unix-like platforms.