# WSL2 Debian automatic unattended re-installation

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm frequently re-installing my wsl2 Debian environment by calling powershell:

```
wsl --terminate Debian 
wsl --unregister Debian
wsl --install Debian
```

The last command blocks next commands execution with prompt:

```
Launching Debian GNU/Linux...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username:
```

My goal is to have the username and password configured automatically without the need of typing them every time, so the whole re-installation will be fully automatic.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: You can try putting the credentials you need in a file and then [redirecting the standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447598/redirecting-standard-input-output-in-windows-powershell) somehow